# Is it something new?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

$W(n)$ is the function that counts number of distinct prime divisors of $n$.  I have been able to prove for any $m$ consecutive integers starting with $1+a$ with the condition $a\leq (m^2-4m)/4$ , there exist a number $n$ in that sequence with the property $W(n)\leq 2$.

> Is it worth to publishing? Is it some thing new?

Comment: Before publishing anything, you should manage to even state your claim properly. I used to think the same as @vrugtehagel, but now I think, that you mean the following: If $m > 4$, given **any** sequence of $m$ consecutive integers, there is at least one integer with at most two distinct prime factors within that sequence.

Comment: @jack but $\omega(2)=1$ right? So for any $m\geq 0$ the sequence $2,3,\ldots,2+m$ contains at least one number $k$ with $\omega(k)=1$ (take $k=2$). Am I missing something?

Comment: I guess that what I am missing, is what @MooS states :).

Comment: Well, this is completely trivial as @Surb pointed out.

Comment: Which one do you mean?

1. For any $m>4$, we can find $m$ consecutive numbers, with $\omega(n) \leq 2$ for all those numbers.

2. For any given sequence of $5$ (of course it suffices to do the $m=5$-case) consecutive numbers, at least one of them satisfies $\omega(n) \leq 2$.

Any clues or references for those statements? If in the second statement, $5$ turns out to be the false bound, is there any bound?

Comment: @jack "Bertrand said it before, and I'll say it again: there is always a prime between $n$ and $2n$". Bertrand's postulate.

Comment: @jack what you say is a weaker version of Bertrand's postulate. A lot weaker, in fact, since your bound is larger, and Bertrand found an $n$ with $\omega(n)=1$, while you only have $\omega(n)\leq 2$

Comment: Bertrand only talkes about (n,2n)

Comment: @PatrickStevens: Chebyshev?

Comment: @charles : what is your idea about what I proved? Is it worth to publish? Is it some thing new?

Comment: @jack: As written your claim is false. I'm not sure what you intended to convey, hopefully something else which is true. But if you can't even get the statement correct I don't have much hope for the proof.

Comment: @Charles You're quite right. My bad.

Answer (score 11):

Short answer: no, don't publish this. If you want to publish anything, you should first make sure you've stated the theorem properly.

---

As has been discussed in the comments, the theorem was a little unclear. But you've explained what theorem you actually meant, so let's state it once more to avoid any confusion.

> **Option 1.** For any integer $m>4$, there exists a sequence of $m$ consecutive integers such that at least one number in that sequence has at most $2$ distinct prime factors.

This is trivial: I can give you any sequence starting at a prime, for example, $$23,24,\cdots,23+m-1$$ and that is such a sequence (since the first number of the sequence, in this case, $23$, has $\omega(23)=1$).

However, let's state the other two options here.

---

> **Option 2.** For any integer $m>4$, there exists a sequence of $m$ consecutive integers all having at most $2$ distinct prime factors.

or

> **Option 3.** For any sequence of $m>4$ consecutive integers, there is a number in that sequence with at most $2$ prime factors.

The third option is disproved by MooS and Patrick Stevens by counterexamples (see MooS's answer or Patrick Stevens' comment).

Option 2 is also disproved by Patrick Stevens, by cleverly noting that any sequence of $30$ consecutive integers contains at least one multiple of $30$, and so at least one number in that sequence has at least $3$ prime factors.

Comment: Option 3 is false: {2664, 2665, 2666, 2667, 2668}

Comment: Option 2 is false. Let $m$ be $31$. Then there is a multiple of $30$ in every range of $m$ integers.

Comment: Damn, Option 2 is unproven so easily, I feel bad, I havent seen this :(

Comment: Furthermore we cannot weaken Option $2$ by replacing '2 distinct prime factors' by a higher amount - say $n$. Because we can just replace $30$ by the product of the first $n+1$ primes to disprove it.

Comment: An interesting question would be: what is the longest sequence of consecutive integers all having $2$ or less distinct prime factors (Alternatively, replace the $2$ by an $n$)? We've bounded it above by $30$ now, but I doubt $29$ such integers exist.

Comment: This is easy to answer, since the sequence $1,2, \dotsc, 29$ does it :)

Comment: Oh man I feel so stupid. I keep thinking things are true after which they're disproved so easily

Comment: It's pretty clear that Option 3 (as well as being false) is not what's being claimed in the question, which says 'there exist $m$ consecutive numbers...'.  My guess is that the OP meant option 2 (though this is also false).

Comment: This thread is a prime example of the old edict, If you want an answer from the internet quickly, post the wrong answer and wait to be corrected. I wonder if this person just wanted to know if his theory was correct. :)

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 5):

After investigating [a big list](https://oeis.org/A001221/b001221.txt) of sequence [A001221](https://oeis.org/A001221), I found $$\omega(30684)=\omega(30685)=\omega(30686)=\omega(30687)=\omega(30688)=3,$$

and

$$\omega(n)=3 \text{ for } 99843 \leq n \leq 99850,$$

hence **Option 3** of the other answer turns out to be false and there is little evidence that increasing $m$ - say $m>8$ - might really help us.